# Fourier expansion of positive and negative fields in In-In formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, path-integral

Recently, I am reading articles regarding In-In formalism, Schwinger-Keldysh formalism.

One advantage of this formalism is it is easy to construct the expectation values of operators in-state without considering any assumption of out-state. (Here In state means past infinity, and out-state means future infinity. In the usual QFT, i.e., for computing $S$-matrix we used in-out i.e., $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ and impose boundary condition on both $\pm \infty$, but here we do not need the information of $+\infty$.)

From the perspective of generating functional, usually, the doubling of the external source procedure happens. i.e., we introduce  $J^+$ and $J^-$ external source and define $$W[J^+, J^-] \propto \int \exp[iS[\phi^+] - S[\phi^-] +J^{+} \phi^+ - J^- \phi^-] d\phi^+ d \phi^-$$ denoting that $+, -$  is the objects from $+$ contour(starting from t_0(we will send $t_0$ to $-\infty$) to some points $t$) and $-$ contour (starting from $t$ and go back to $-\infty$).

[image]

I want to know the form of Fourier expansion for $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$. In the usual QFT, we have $$\phi(t,x) = \int d^3k \tilde{\phi}(t,p) e^{ip\cdot x},$$ but how about $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$? Following the above contour the only difference between $+$ and $-$ is the direction of time....